# Shortest path on PHP array

Tags: php, image, shortest-path

I am looking for an answer and everything I tried so far is failing. This is my sample array displayed as an image:

[image: array to use]

But this array is pretty big and this one is just a scaled version of original one.

So I tried djikstra but it looks for perfect path and cannot work on such a big arrays. Each cluster is labeled and some of them ( too small ones are removed from display ).

I was wondering if BFS could do the job here, but I am not sure about this. Basically I need short path throught red cluster which goes from Top to the Bottom OR from Left to the Right, so only two clusters would get checked ( 1 and 12 ) since only they are connecting two sides. The path doesn't need to be perfect, I need to have reliable path at good speed for about 512x512 arrays.

Each connection has same weight with neighbours and that would be 1

Thanks for your time

Comment: This may be more appropriately asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can also use the [A* search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), it should be faster than Dijstra as it uses heuristics. I think it should fine the right answer always for this case.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will try A* and write how it went.